# Last executor hangs with spark-sql doing left outer join

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I am using spark-sql 1.2 on a 300 node cluster with YARN. I am performing a left outer join with larger table = 600GB and smaller table 176MB that I cache.

I run 300 executors with 2GB per executor and 2GB for driver.

I use a date range filter and condition in the where clause.

Program runs fine until last executor times out and never returns after multiple retries.

The data is skewed but I do not think that is the problem.

The last step in program is a save to Text file.

The two tables are hive tables in rcfile format.

The large table has about 90 columns and the join is on one column.

- Could it be that one executor is preserving the entire large table before going to where clause?
- How can I turn up logging to get an idea what is going on?

Comment: why so many executor with so few memory each?

Comment: I am not sure how to tune memory. What would be a good memory setting for this kind of job? I have tried 4GB with same results.

Comment: You have a dedicated chapter in the official Spark documentation about tuning. I advice you to read it!